# Integrating with nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus

I need to integrate a .net2.0 app with nservicebus. Actually, I just need that this .net2.0 sends a message to a nservicebus queue.

Should I just create it by myself?
Theres any trick I should watch out, so when I upgrade to, lets say, nservicebus4 it wont break ?

Answer (score 0):

To "integrate" an app with NServiceBus simply include binary references to *NServiceBus.dll*, *NServiceBus.Core.dll*, and *NServiceBus.Host.exe* in your solution.

Try downloading the [samples](http://docs.particular.net/samples/).

Answer (score 0):

using .net 2.0 will be a problem with trying to reference nservicebus.  i don't think there is any straightforward way to reference nservicebus from a 2.0 application (outside of using a very old version, which would have problems too).

the shortest path would probably be to upgrade the framework version to 4.0.  why not just do this?  if you're talking about making changes and sending messages, you must have access to the source code and the ability to change it.

next after that might be to serialize a message yourself and send it with system.messaging.  i think this is what you mean by "create it by myself."  you'd definitely want to test that your messages still work if updating to another version of nservicebus on the handling side.  udi is insistent on backward compatibility in updating versions of software, so i'd expect nservicebus would exhibit this probably and that your messages would still work, but you would want to make sure.